# NGINX: Same Hash for multiple upstreams

Tags: nginx, hash, load-balancing

I've multiple upstreams with same 2 servers in different ports for different apps, but I would need it to keep a consistent connection to the server.
Example:

```
 upstream APP {
         ip_hash;
         server 10.10.10.1:1111;
         server 10.10.10.2:1111;
         }      

 upstream APP_HTTP {
         ip_hash;
         server 10.10.10.1:2222;
         server 10.10.10.2:2222;
         }  

 upstream APP_WS {
         ip_hash;
         server 10.10.10.1:3333;
         server 10.10.10.2:3333;
         }       


....

 location /APP {
                proxy_pass http://APP;
        }

 location /APP_HTTP {
                proxy_pass http://APP_HTTP;
        }

 location /APP_WS {
                proxy_pass http://APP_WS;
        }
```

So if a user is redirected at APP starting point to server 10.10.10.1, I need to guarantee that for APP_HTTP and APP_WS goes as well to 10.10.10.1.

Is it possible? How?
IP_Hash seems to not be working as I would expect.

Thanks
Best regards